# Can't get rid of filesort on joined query sorting on second table

Tags: mysql, join, index-tuning, sorting

For some reason, this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM biz as b INNER JOIN listings as l ON b.id = l.biz_id
  WHERE l.pub_id = 14 AND b.cat_id=310 ORDER BY l.level DESC, l.random DESC LIMIT 5;
```

says it would use a filesort:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref                                    | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref    | [...]         | cat_id           | 4       | const                                  | 1160 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | ref    | [...]         | biz_id           | 4       | b.id                                   |    1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

I have tried setting up several indexes on `listings` that include biz_id, pub_id, level and random, but no need to bore you with my failings; what would be the proper index to use to avoid a filesort in this query?  Or is it impossible?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5

Comment: Only solution i found to do this is to create a temporary view i database and use that view as a table. creating view ..
create or replace view [view name] [cols][query]

Comment: Hm, have you tried a composite index on `(pub_id, level, random, biz_id)`?